# Macro Conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I a creating a function in excel using VBA Macro, where it will check if there is a empty cell in a certain column. For example I need to check column A to E and each columns needs to check if there are empty cells, it its empty it will be filled with color red and then add an error comment in column J like " Column A is empty. Please check." (The error is the empty cell) I already have a code for filling the empty cell with color red, what I am having trouble is the error comment because if there are empty cells in different columns but in the same row like column A and column B is empty the Error comment must be "Column A, B is empty. Please check" I just need to insert ", B" in the sentence. And I am having trouble in that condition. please help me

I will attach the code for error comment I just need the condition for inserting ",B" inside the existing comment. Thank you in advance
(Note: there are other comments for other functions that I created.)

```
'Add Error Comment to Column J

cellAddress= "J" & i
tgtValue = "column A is empty. Please check" 

If Range(cellAddress).Value = "" Then 
   Range(celladdress).Value = "->" + tgtValue

Elself Range(cellAddress).Value <> "" And InStr(1,Range(cellAddress).Value, tgtValue, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
     Range(cellAddress).Value = Range(cellAddress).Value + " " + tgtvalue

End If

End If
```

None at the moment as I wasn't able to figure it out. I got this error comment from other functions that I created

Comment: Please share the complete (relevant) code (at least the complete loop i.e. `For i =... Next i`).

Answer (score 0):

First, your `Elself` statement has a lowercase l instead of an uppercase I (in uppercase it says ELSELF).

You might get a better answer if you share more of your code, but based on what you have, to add ",B", try assigning the new value like this:

```
Range(cellAddress).Value = Replace(Range(cellAddress).Value, " is empty", ",B is empty")
```

Comment: I will try it, but is there other method that I can try?

Comment: For modifying the string, `Replace` is the best method here. But I wonder if you have written the same code 5 times, for each of the 5 columns you are checking. If that is the case, there is probably a way to just write the code once within a loop, and loop through it 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```vb
Sub CheckEmpty()

    Dim rw As Range, msg, sep, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet                     'for example
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rw In ws.Range("A2:E10").rows   'loop over rows in your range
        msg = ""                             'clear message and separator
        sep = ""
        For Each c In rw.Cells               'loop cells in row
            If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then         'empty?
                c.Interior.Color = vbRed
                'collect the column letter
                msg = msg & sep & Replace(c.Address(False, False), c.Row, "")
                sep = ", "         'populate separator after first value
            Else
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'OK - clear any fill
            End If
        Next c
        'add/clear message
        With ws.Cells(rw.Row, "J")
            .Value = IIf(Len(msg) > 0, "Column(s) " & msg & " should be populated", "")
        End With
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- `A1:E10` is for demo purpose. You can add more code lines to determine the source data range.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub DEMO()
    Dim rRow As Range, rCell As Range, rBlank As Range
    Dim sCol As String
    Const DATA_RNG = "A1:E10"  ' data range, modify as needed
    Const CMT_COL = "I" ' comment column
    Const CMT = "Column @ is empty. Please check" ' @ is a placeholder for columns
    Set rBlank = Range(DATA_RNG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) ' get the blank cells
    If Not rBlank Is Nothing Then
        For Each rRow In rBlank.Rows
            sCol = ""
            For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                sCol = sCol & "," & Split(rCell.Address, "$")(1)
            Next
            ' Update comment
            Cells(rRow.Cells(1).Row, CMT_COL) = Replace(CMT, "@", Mid(sCol, 2))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008930)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008907)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)